# c program to read file and count words specified in array

Tags: arrays, c, file, count

I'm trying to read a file containing a paragraph, count the number of times specific words occur (words that I have specified and stored in an array) and then print that result to another file that would look something like,

```
systems, 2
computer, 3
programming, 6
```

and so on. Currently, all this code does is spit out every word in the paragraph and their respective counts. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    FILE* in;
    FILE* out;

    char arr1[13][100] = { "systems", "programming", "computer", "applications", "language", "machine"};
    int arr2[180] = {0};
    int count = 0;
    char temp[150];

    in = fopen("out2.dat", "r");
    out = fopen("out3.dat", "w");

    while (fscanf(in, "%s", temp) != EOF)
    {
        int i, check = 8;
        for (i = 0;i < count;i++)
        {
            if (strcmp(temp, arr1[i]) == 0)
            {
                arr2[i]++;
                check = 1;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (check == 1) continue;
        strcpy(arr1[count], temp);
        arr2[count++] = 1;
    }
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < count; i++)
        fprintf(out, "%s, %d\n", arr1[i], arr2[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Would you provide the sample of input file containing a paragraph?

Comment: I don't understand the problem.  It works for me https://onlinegdb.com/2mDHY486-

Comment: C general-purpose, procedural computer programming language supporting structured programming, lexical
variable scope, recursion, static type system. design, C provides constructs that map efficiently
typical machine instructions. found lasting use applications previously coded assembly language. Such
applications include operating systems various application software computer architectures that 
range supercomputers PLCs embedded systems. 

<<thats a copy of on of the paragraphs i'm trying to read>>

Comment: Sorry I should have stated that the paragraph doesn't just have those words in it. So the problem i'm having is that it is telling me all of the words occurrences rather than just the words i've specified in the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The use of `count` does not make much sense throughout this program.

It is declared as `int count = 0;`, and then used as the upper bound in this loop

```
for (i = 0; i < count; i++)
```

limiting which search words will be used. This also means that this loop will not be entered on the first iteration of the surrounding `while` loop.

As such, `check != 1`, so after this `count` is used as the index in `arr1` at which the currently read "word" will be copied into

```
strcpy(arr1[count], temp);
```

which makes absolutely no sense. Why overwrite data you are searching for?

Then `count` is incremented to `1` after being used to set the first element of `arr2` to `1`.

On the second iteration of the `while` loop, the `for` loop will run for exactly one iteration, comparing the newly read "word" (`temp`) against the first element of `arr1` (which is now the last "word" read).

If this matches: the first element in `arr2` is incremented from `1` to `2`, the string copy is skipped, and `count` is not incremented.

If this does not match, the new "word" is copied into the second element of `arr1`, the second element of `arr2` is set to `1`, and `count` is incremented to `2`.

This spirals out of control from here.

Given the input shown above, this accesses `arr1` out-of-bounds when `count` reaches `13`.

With files that have a small selection of data (<= 13 unique "words", lengths < 100), this may accidentally "work" by populating `arr1` with the words from the file. This will have the end effect of showing you the counts of each "word" in the input file.

---

Eventually, you will invoke [Undefined Behavior](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/behavior) when one of the following occurs:

- `fscanf(in, "%s", temp)` reads a string that overflows the `temp` buffer.
- `count` exceeds the bounds of `arr1` or `arr2`.
- `strcpy(arr1[count], temp);` copies a string that overflows a buffer in `arr1`.
- Either `fopen` fail.

---

In addition to being unsafe, `fscanf(in, "%s", temp)` will consider anything other than whitespace as being part of a valid string. This includes trailing punctuation, which may or may not be an issue depending on which tokens you want to match (`systems.` vs. `systems`). You may need more robust parsing.

In any case, either create an array of structures composed of search words and frequencies, or, create two arrays of the same length to represent this data:

```
const char *words[6] = { "systems", "programming", "computer", "applications", "language", "machine"};
unsigned freq[6] = { 0 };
```

There is no need to copy anything. Remember to check if `fopen` fails, and to limit `%s` when reading as not to overflow the input buffer.

The rest of the program looks similar: test each input "word" against all search words; increment the corresponding frequency if a match.

An example using an array of structures:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    struct {
        const char *word;
        unsigned freq;
    } search_words[] = {
        { "systems", 0 },
        { "programming", 0 },
        { "computer", 0 },
        { "applications", 0 },
        { "language", 0 },
        { "machine", 0 }
    };

    size_t length = sizeof search_words / sizeof *search_words;

    FILE *input_file = fopen("out2.dat", "r");
    FILE *output_file = fopen("out3.dat", "w");

    if (!input_file || !output_file) {
        fclose(input_file);
        fclose(output_file);
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not access files.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    char word[256];

    while (1 == fscanf(input_file, "%255s", word))
        for (size_t i = 0; i < length; i++)
            if (0 == strcmp(word, search_words[i].word))
                search_words[i].freq++;

    fclose(input_file);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < length; i++)
        fprintf(output_file, "%s, %u\n",
                search_words[i].word,
                search_words[i].freq);

    fclose(output_file);
}
```

`cat out3.dat`:

```
systems, 1
programming, 1
computer, 2
applications, 2
language, 1
machine, 1
```